# Is neutrino really a point (fundamental) particle?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, magnetic-moment

Having a non-zero magnetic moment, was a proof for neutron to not to be fundamental particle. Now we have enough literature or research work over neutrinos that have proved that neutrinos, being a neutral particle, also have their own tiny magnetic moment. So, does this fact prove that neutrinos also are not fundamental particles?

Comment: Only experiments can prove that neutrino is not a fundamental particle. You can conceive theories in which a neutrino is made up of 20 parton-like subparticles, but if you cannot measure effects of these partons in a lab/research facility, then your theory is pretty much dry mathematics.

Comment: @particle121 With the second sentence of your question, are you saying that the neutrino magnetic moment has been measured to be non-zero? That doesn't sound right to me. Can you provide a citation?

Comment: Is there any experimental evidence for the existence of magnetic moment of neutrinos? The fact that they have mass allows the existence of magnetic moment in some extended versions of the Standard Model.

Comment: I don't believe your first sentence is correct. For example, the electron also has a magnetic moment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment

Comment: @Rococo Electron is a charged particle. So it is understood for this to have a non-zero magnetic moment. While neutrino is an electrically neutral particle and still having non-zero magnetic moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neutrino oscillations have implied a small mass for the neutrino. This forces an extension of the standard model , with the particle table

[image: elempart]

having still a point nature in the lagrangian for the now [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

The masses of the neutrinos are limits and are very small.

[This presentation](http://nucla.physics.ucla.edu/sites/default/files/NeutrinoMagneticMoment_2012Nov8.pdf) discusses how a point particle, i.e. not a composite one, can have a [magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_of_an_electron):

[image: neutrino magmoment]

So in a sense due to the perturbative expansion and the virtual loops, once the neutrino has a mass it acquires a magnetic moment by the higher order loops.

> So, does this fact prove that neutrinos also are not fundamental particles?

The moment is a validation of quantum field theoretical calculations, and has a very small value with respect to the Bohr magneton which is the order of magnitude for protons and neutrons. It is a higher order QFT correction ( [anomalous magnetic moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment) calculated for all point particle moments